# Vscode, git diff view: how show only changes

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm new to VSCode and can't find online if is possible to have my favorite diff view mode: I want to see only the lines changed - and the closer ones - not the entire file with the highlighting of the changes.

E.g.: in the image I've deleted\added 2 lines: one at 8 and one at 90.
I'd like to see only those changes, not the entire file.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**edit:** there is now a button, in the toolbar at the top, to collapse/uncollapse unchanged parts of the file (even if you are still in a real text editor):

[image: collapse unchanged parts of file]

previous (no more accurate) answer:

<s>I think that's not possible because what is provided here is a real text editor where you can edit the content of the file.</s>

With the toolbar at the top...

[image: vscode diff toolbar]

... you could still:

- go to previous/next change (`Alt+Shift+f5`/`Alt+f5`)
- toggle to display inline diff

Comment: Sorry, but the screenshot provided is already the diff view of the "Source Control" pane (my bad if it was not clear, I didn't grab the toolbar above\on the left).
The inline view isn't anyway what I'm looking  for, it shows all the files, not only the "lines around the changes"

Comment: @Giuseppe I understood the question well. That's why I told you that's not possible in the first line ;) and tried to provide an explanation why and some workarounds that I hope will help you a little...

Comment: oh ok I didn't understood correctly the first part of the answer. I actually had already seen those commands you've pointed out, but thanks for the explanation nevertheless.

Comment: @Giuseppe But I'm also not very fond of that. Perhaps if vscode could fold the code with some gutter accordions by default, that would be great....

Comment: This worked quite well, which is pretty cool. The option also appears in the command palette. To access it, simply press 'shift + command + p', then search for 'inline' to toggle it.

Answer (score 7):

Add these properties in the settings.json file and restart VS Code.

```
"diffEditor.experimental.useVersion2": true,
"diffEditor.experimental.collapseUnchangedRegions": true,
```

[image]

[Original GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3562#issuecomment-1609725434)

Answer (score 2):

Such feature request is tracked here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3562. You can let developers know you'd like to see it implemented with a thumbs-up reaction to the first post.